# Abs() - issue with absolute value function in PHP

Tags: php, logic

Can anyone explain why this code does this in regards to abs() (absolute value) - 
In my code it will display 'GREATER' - although 0.50 is never GREATER than 0.5, am I missing out something here with the abs function?

```
$logic = abs(1.83333333333 - 2.33333333333);  // 0.50
$limit = 0.50;

if ($logic > $limit) {
    echo 'IS GREATER';
} else {
    echo 'IS NOT GREATER';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing floating point numbers to abs you will get a floating point number as result. In that case you can experience problems with the floating point representation: a floating point is never absolutely precise, thus you are most likely getting a number that is not exactly 0.50 but something like 0.500000...01. You could try to round the result to the desired precision (in your case I guess it is two) with the php round function.

Comment: Well, a floating point number is always precise, but not always accurate. Sometimes it is both.  Sorry, just trying to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way floating point math works, your absolute value `$logic` results in this value:

```
0.50000000000000022204
```

which *is* greater than 0.5

NB: above evaluated using Javascript which uses double precision math for all numbers:

```
Math.abs(1.83333333333 - 2.33333333333).toFixed(20)
```

Comment: Just out of interest, how do you get this exact value? When doing a var_dump on the abs it just shows "float 0.5" rather then the above.

Comment: @Oldskool using Javascript - `Math.abs(1.83333333333 - 2.33333333333).toFixed(20)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to round as suggested by @Aldo's answer and your server supports the GMP math functions, you could use [`gmp_abs()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-abs.php) instead.  This way you don't run into PHP's inherent floating point problems.

Answer (score 0):

Never compare floats by equality - user the epsilon technique instead [PHP: Floating Point Numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

```
define('EPSILON', 1.0e-8);
$logic = abs(1.83333333333 - 2.33333333333);  // 0.50
$limit = 0.50;
$diff = $logic - $limit;
if (abs($diff) < EPSILON)
   echo 'IS EQUAL';
else
   echo 'IS NOT EQUAL';
```

Comment: the trouble with the epsilon method is that only gives you (approximately) _equal_ or _not equal_.  It's not good for _greater than_ or _less than_ because the second call to `abs()` throws away the sign.