# ABS function in php showing incorrect result

Tags: php

I just started to learn few days ago basics in PHP and can't see why this happen. I have this simple [ABS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) function which return undesired result. I have value in database saved like:

> -0.00069026

Then on the page I'm showing it like this

```
abs($sum['sum'])
```

and the output that I get is this

> 0.00069026000000005

All that I want is to remove this minus(-) sign in front of the number.

Update:
I've tried with str_replace but got wired error `Indirect modification of overloaded element of Sum has no effect`

```
str_replace('-', '', '', $sum['sum'])
```

Comment: It's because you're working with floating point. You can remove it with `str_replace()` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abs() - issue with absolute value function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804842/abs-issue-with-absolute-value-function-in-php)

Comment: I've updated my question. Is not duplicate. I've tried both suggestions there `Math.abs` and `gmp_abs()` got this error `Use of undefined constant Math - assumed 'Math'` edit: I just saw that Math is for javascript.

Comment: You shouldn't pass 4 arguments like that (the 4th is a count-parameter). 
It should be `str_replace('-', '', $sum['sum'])`. https://3v4l.org/NHKqF and http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: This still showing the same result as abs `str_replace("-", "", $sum['sum'])` still the result on page is `0.00069026000000005`

Comment: Any idea why my result is till like this?

Comment: My PHP version is `PHP Version 7.0.14-1~dotdeb+8.1`